# PHP files with 'cmt' extension (?)

Tags: php

This might sound a bit silly.
I have to update a website with a new interface, and although I received the old code I am lost. (As far as I know, I received the complete website, phpPgAdmin included)

Most of the files are .cmt but I'm pretty sure it's PHP, index.cmt for instance is

```
<?
include_once('redirected.php');
exit();
function get_lang_from_ip() {
    $client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $client_hostname = gethostbyaddr($client_ip);

    if ($client_ip != $client_hostname) {
        $dom_arr = split('\.',$client_hostname);
        $lang_id = ($dom_arr[sizeof($dom_arr)-1] == 'hu') ? 'hu' : 'en';
    } else {
        $lang_id = 'hu';
    }
    return $lang_id;
}

function set_target() {
    $valid_lang_arr = array('hu', 'en');
    if (isset($_GET['lang_id']) && in_array($_GET['lang_id'], $valid_lang_arr)) {
        $lang_id = $_GET['lang_id'];
    } elseif (isset($_COOKIE['lang_id']) && in_array($_COOKIE['lang_id'], $valid_lang_arr)) {
        $lang_id = $_COOKIE['lang_id'];
    } else {
        $lang_id = 'hu'; //get_lang_from_ip();
    }
    setcookie('lang_id', $lang_id, time()+3600*24*365, '/');
    return $lang_id;
}

header('Connection: close');
header('Location: /'.set_target().'/');
?>
```

The .php files however don't begin with the `<?` short opening tag, but with `<?php` instead. And most importantly, the .cmt files are not parsed, if I navigate to the index.cmt I see the code in the browser, and thus I can't even put the old layout back together.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Many of the frameworks uses other than `.php` so don't get lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a `.htaccess` file, and include the following:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .cmt
```

That should allow PHP to be executed on .cmt file extensions.

*Please note that this fix can only be used on Apache web servers or others that support `.htaccess`.*

---

Although, if possible, I'd recommend that you change all `.cmt` file extensions to their appropriate counter part, `.php`.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Whati if OP uses nginx or anything else but Apache?

Answer (score 3):

While @Josh Foskett has a valid answer, I think an actual solution would be to go through your files and rename the `.cmt` extensions to `.php` for scalability and to avoid confusion down the road.

Consider "phasing out" the legacy extensions by bringing them up to the current extension standard. Make this a project, not a quick fix, and I think you'll be much happier with your code base.

Comment: ehm... I would first bring the site to a working state, see that everything works and *then* do the refactoring..

Comment: @yi_H That's subjective, so to each his own. "bring the site to a working state" could be anything from renaming the extensions to adding a line in the .htaccess to accommodate for said extensions. I say always write code that can be used later on, and try not to write code that will be deleted later on.

Comment: I don't see how your mantra is relevant here, we are talking about 1 htaccess line..

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your server to parse `.cmt` files as PHP.

Also, both `<?` and `<?php` are valid opening tags for PHP, though the short version might be turned off in PHP settings (usually define in `php.ini` somewhere in the filesystem).

Comment: He definitely does not need to configure his web browser ;)

Comment: @AlienWebguy Heh, easiest solutions (renaming `.cmt` to `.php`) are the best ones :)

Answer (score 1):

Enable `short_open_tag` in php.ini.

This will make sure, that php is actually executed, if it's *included* from an other file. It still won't execute, `.cmt` files directly, but if you have main `.php` entry files, that's exactly the behaviour you need.